# Is it possible to build a linked list without the help of self referential structure?

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Is it possible to build a linked list without the help of self referential structure? I.e. like this just using a pointer:

```
struct list{
    int data;
    int *nxt;
};
```

instead of

```
struct list{
    int data;
    struct list *nxt;
};
```

Comment: `nxt` must point to a list element, not an `int`. There is no portable way to make the `int *nxt` declaration work. There are ways to do it, but they are all hacks which will restrict the portability, readability, and reliability of your code without any advantage.

Comment: What is the point of doing it that way? Perhaps if you explained what you are actually trying to achieve then someone might have a good suggestion.

Comment: I think the key part is `without the help of self referential structure`. Probably, by `int *nxt;` the OP intended to say `<whatever type except struct list> *nxt;`.

Comment: @chatraed I understand what OP wants. The question is not "what" but "why".

Comment: @Alan Au: Why? Becase, for example, that is the way the linux kernel linked lists actually [work](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/).

Comment: @chatraed That's **a** reason and fair enough. But the reason in this case should come from the OP and not someone else. The point is trying to understand what the OP wants to achieve so that a good answer can be given. The reason you have given may or may not be what the OP is intending.

Comment: @AlanAu I am a beginner.It just came in my mind when i was in my contemplative mood and thank you all for a quick reply,I have learnt a new  thing today.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

What you're proposing is [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning), and you'll probably get away with it with most compilers on most platforms, but there's not a single good reason to do it in the first place and many good reasons not to.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at how linked lists are implemented in the Linux kernel.

Compared to the classical linked lists:

```
struct my_list{
    void *myitem;
    struct my_list *next;
    struct my_list *prev;
};
```

using a linked list in the linux kernel looks like:

```
struct my_cool_list{
    struct list_head list; /* kernel's list structure */
    int my_cool_data;
};
```

[Source](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/)

Comment: But isn't list_head a self-referential structure? All you've done is hide the circularity in a header file.

Comment: @rici: `struct list_head` is completely unrelated to `struct my_cool_list`. Where is the connection, I don't get you.

Comment: self-referential means that it refers to itself. iow, struct list_head includes a member pointer to a struct list_head, making it self-referential.

Comment: @rici: Yes, obviously the various `struct list_head` are interconnected. However, the circularity and self-reference is lost between the structure that holds the useful data and its members.

Comment: Technically, this isn't self-referential, so it is an appropriate answer to this question. +1 from me, to offset the stupid -1 which seems to have no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could use `void *` instead of `struct list *` as your `nxt` member. For example:

```
struct list {
    int data;
    void *nxt;
};
```

Alternatively, if you're prepared to build in a guarantee that the nodes of the list will be stored into an array (which is great for cache locality and insertion speed), you could use a `size_t`.

```
struct list {
     int data;
     size_t nxt;
};
```

If your implementation provides `uintptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`), you could merge these two types into one:

```
struct list {
    int data;
    uintptr_t nxt;
};
```

Comment: Why storing the nodes of a list in array, since each list node knows its neighbour(s) already?

Comment: @chatraed Aside from better cache locality, one can reduce the number of calls to `malloc` (or similar) by allocating (or otherwise declaring) multiple nodes at once. Pointers to `nxt` items are required so that the list can be rearranged without physically moving each item.

Comment: Is there an open-source piece of software putting it in practice?

Comment: I don't know of any off the top of my head, though I'm sure there is... It's a concept I learnt from an algorithms book, after all.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use parallel arrays as your "heap"<sup>1</sup>, with one array containing your data (whether a scalar or a struct) and another to store the index of the next "node" in the list, like:

```
int data[N];
int next[N];
```

You'll need two "pointers" - one to point to the first element in the list, and one to point to the first available "node" in your "heap".

```
int head;
int free;
```

You'll initialize all the elements in the "next" array to "point" to the next element, except for the last element which points to "null":

```
for ( int i = 1; i < N-1; i++ )
  next[i-1] = i;
next[N-1] = -1;
free = 0;  // first available "node" in the heap
head = -1; // list is empty, head is "null"
```

Inserting a new element in the list looks something like this (assuming an ordered list):

```
if ( free != -1 )
{
  int idx = free;    // get next available "node" index;
  free = next[free]; // update the free pointer 
  data[idx] = newValue;
  next[idx] = -1;

  if ( head == -1 )
  {
    head = idx;
  }
  else if ( data[idx] < data[head] )
  {
    next[idx] = head;
    head = idx;
  }
  else
  {
    int cur = head;    
    while ( next[cur] != -1 && data[idx] >= data[next[cur]] )
      cur = next[cur];
    next[idx] = next[cur];
    next[cur] = idx;
  }
}
```

Deleting an element at `idx` is pretty straightforward:

```
int cur = head;
while ( next[cur] != idx && next[cur] != -1 )
  cur = next[cur];

if ( next[cur] == idx )
{
  next[cur] = next[idx];  // point to the element following idx
  next[idx] = free;       // add idx to the head of the free list
  free = idx;             
}
```

Advantages of this approach:

1. No dynamic memory management;
2. No self-referential structures;
3. Data items are stored contiguously in memory, which may lead to better caching performance.

Disadvantages:

1. In this simple approach, list sizes are fixed;
2. Any usefully large arrays will have to be declared `static`, meaning your binary may have a large footprint;
3. The convention of using `-1` as "null" means you have to use a signed type for your indices, which reduces the number of available elements for a given array type.

You could certainly use `0` as "null" and count all your indices from `1`; this allows you to use unsigned types like `size_t` for your indices, meaning you can make your arrays pretty much as big as the system will allow.  It's just that `0` is a valid array index whereas `-1` (usually) isn't, which is why I chose it for this example.

---

<sup>1.  Welcome to my Data Structures class, ca. 1987, which was taught using Fortran 77. Parallel arrays were pretty much the answer for everything (lists, trees, queues, etc.)</sup>

Comment: If you're locking the OP into a single form of storage duration, I'm not sure I'd agree that "No dynamic memory management" is an advantage.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour:  Well, this example is deliberately simplistic.  You can obviously allocate the arrays dynamically, even extend them as necessary (just have to adjust your free list to accommodate the new elements).  But you don't need to manage memory for individual nodes.  And if you know your list is going to be small (on the order of a few kilobytes), why bother with dynamic memory at all?